# What is Spark SQL's LIMIT operator and why is it used here?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a query, executed using Spark SQL:

```
sql = '''select promo.promo_group_code
,promo.promo_desc
,promo.promo_start_dttm
,promo.promo_end_dttm
from tuk_ssewh.promo_dim_c promo
where promo_group_code = 'ABC123'
'''
promosDf = sqlContext.sql(sql)
promosDf.show()
```

It returns 6 rows. If I look at the query details I see
[image]

I'm intrigued as to why the Limit operator is being used, and why is it "Limit 21'. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `.show()` will, by default, show 20 rows.